# magento change add to cart from category custom design

Tags: attributes

how can i modify add to cart page from admin > custom design update.

Basically i want to add custome block next to add to cart button based on current category products ,

as of now it loads

frontend\themename\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml

but i want to override it with other based on current category how can it be done .

Please guide me with same

i tried using below code in category > custom design (with apply to products)

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>catalog/product/view/a.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the 'catalog_product_view' tags

```
<reference name="product.info.addtocart">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>catalog/product/view/my_new_template.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: can it be done via module also

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: yes.................